# How can I make different functions from each of these statements?

Tags: c++, function, file

I have this code and I have to do two things. One is to get the numbers from a file that has already been made. Two is to make each problem into a function. Such as a function for getting the minimum number and a function to get the highest number. If I could get help with at least the one to make each one a function, I will be very thankful. Also I would just like to get the lowest. I can figure out the rest that are asked in the code.

I have tried this, I know it is not correct but I am not sure what parameters to use.

I know the code is wrong but I am struggling to figure out how.

```
int getLowest(int arrayNum[], smallest);

int main()
{
    string fileName;
    ifstream inputFile;
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 12;
    int numbers[ARRAY_SIZE], smallest, largest, sum, average;

    //Prompt user to insert the file name
    cout << "Enter the name of imput file: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    //Open file
        inputFile.open(fileName);

    //If it successfully opens
    if (inputFile)
    {
        // Read the numbers and get the lowest, highest, sum and average of 
        // the numbers.
    cout << numbers << " numbers read from input file.\n"
         << "The lowest value is " << getLowest(numbers) << endl;
    }

        else
    {
        //Display error message
        cout << "Error, this file does not exist.";
    }
}

int getLowest(int arrayNum[], int smallest)
{
    int temp = arrayNum[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < smallest; i++) 
        {
        if (temp < arrayNum[i])
            temp = arrayNum[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: _"make each problem into a function"_ -- where do these problems come from? Maybe try writing the question starting with the assumption that we know nothing about what you're trying to do? Start at the beginning and don't jump ahead.

Answer (score 0):

First, to check if a file is open, use `if(inputFile.is_open()){}`. `if(inputFile){}` will (I believe) perform something like `if(&inputFile != 0x00000000){}`, which I don't think you want.

If you are having trouble reading the file, use

```cpp
for(unsigned char i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
    inputFile >> numbers[i];                    // note the `>>` operator
}
```

For `getLowest()`, I'm  guessing you want something more like

```cpp
#define ARRAY_SIZE 12                           // a macro
int getLowest(int* arrayNum, int& smallest){
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++){        // in your code, if smallest was > 
        if(temp < arrayNum[i]){                 // array length, run-time err
            temp = arrayNum[i];
        }
    }
    smallest = temp;
    return temp;
}
```

You just had a few critical errors in your code. I hope this helps.

Comment: HI, thank you. I am still a beginner at this and struggle with some problems. Even at trying to describe what I am trying to do but thank you for your help.